# Bring all rows into an array PHP

Tags: php

Good day one and all,

This php statement seems to be bringing back only the one row from a table. How would I modify it so that it would bring back all rows?

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array())

  {

$array = array("UserID" => $row['UserID'], "runDate" => $row['runDate'],"firstName" => $row['firstName'], "Time" => $row['Time'], "Distance" => $row['Distance']);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$array = array(/** */);
```

to

```
$array[] = array(/** */);
```

That's about it.

Answer (score 3):

I would use:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){

   $array[] = $row;

}
```

By using the `$row` variable it keeps your array keys the same as the Database Column names

Comment: +1. He isn't changing the keys from the ones held in the database, so creating his own array instead of assigning $row is entirely pointless.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (I have not tested it though):

```
$all_rows = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
  $all_rows[] = array("UserID" => $row['UserID'], "runDate" => $row['runDate'],"firstName" => $row['firstName'], "Time" => $row['Time'], "Distance" => $row['Distance']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
foreach($result->fetch_array() as $row)

{
    $array["UserID"][] = $row['UserID'];
    $array["runDate"][] = $row['runDate'];
    $array["firstName"][] = $row['firstName'];
    $array["Time"][] = $row['Time'];
    $array["Distance"][] = $row['Distance'];
}
```

and then checkit out :

```
var_dump($array);
```